# How does the special offer Parallels Desktop 11 for Mac "Upgrade" work?

Tags: applications, upgrade, parallels-desktop

So, my dad has an old version of Parallels at home. We can't find the original software box or disk but it is running on the iMac. I wanted to maybe avail of the (soon to finish) special offer of the €50 for the "Upgrade."

My question is: if I buy the software online and download it, do I need to have an activation code for the original version of Parallels? I can't find any information on the parallels website and can't find any support for this.
 Thanks.